# How can I use url query string when working with ejs

Tags: mysql, node.js, ejs

Is there a way to pass a query string inside a href in ejs? I want to be able to click on a link and use the the link parameter inside my db query. Here's the code I'm playing with at the moment

```
//ejs view
<% if (data) { %>
<% data.forEach(function(car) { %>
    <div class="card mb-3">
        <a href="/cars/:id">
            <div class="card-body text-center text-capitalize">
                <div class="card-title"><%= car.brand %></div>
                <p class="card-text text-muted"><%= car.color %> / <%= car.engine_type %></p>
            </div>
        </a>
    </div>
<% }) %>
<% } %>
```

In my routes file, I want to query like this

```
router.get('/cars/:id?', function(req, res) {
var carId = req.params.id;

res.locals.connection.query('SELECT * FROM cars WHERE id = ?', [carId], function(err, row) {
    if(err) {
        console.log(err);
    } else {
        res.send(row);
    }
});
});
```

Right now i get a 304 status when i run my app because i'm not passing back the id. How can i pass it back? I have no idea and haven't been successful with my search.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Eventually found that the id can be passed in the href same way the car object is displayed with ejs. In this case the `href="/cars/<%= car.id %>"`